# Spring Security call another Authentication Provider even the first provider is failed

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I used Authentication providers in Spring Security. I have two Authentication Providers: `LocalAuthenticationProvider` and `RemoteAuthenticationProvider`. The authentication flow is that

1. the application checks credential at local db
2. if local authentication is passed, need to call `RESTful` Web service to authenticate
   the credential.
3. if local authentication is failed, assume
   authentication failed and response `401`.

> ```
> @Override
> protected void configure(
>     AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
>     auth.authenticationProvider(localProvider).authenticationProvider(remoteProvider);
> }
> ```

`LocalAuthenticationProvider` throws `AuthenticationException` if credential is failed. If credentials is `passed`, it returns `null`.

My problem is Spring Security Framework calls `RemoteAuthenticationProvider` even `LocalAuthenticationProvider` is `failed`.

When I remove `RemoteAuthenticationProvider` from `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` provider list, it works even `LocalAuthenticationProvider` is `failed`.

I would like to know how can I achieve this Authentication flow. These two providers are depend on each other.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Javadoc for `ProviderManager` it would seem that if your first provider was to throw an `AccountStatusException` then authentication would not proceed to the second provider:

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/ProviderManager.html

> The exception to this process [providers being invoked in order until one passes] is when a provider throws an
>   `AccountStatusException`, **in which case no further providers in the list
>   will be queried**.